# Creating complex HTML with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, loops, clone, appendto

Im having trouble creating complex html with javascript or, preferably, jQuery. My goal is to create this:

```
<div class="clone"> <div class="nested_clone> <span> </span> </div> </div>
```

purely with jquery and run a loop where i append it a number of times to a container.
I know i can create html with jquery and add a class with the following code:

```
clone = $("<div></div>",{ class:"clone"});
nested_clone = $("<div></div>",{class:"nested_clone"});
nested_span = $("<span></span>");
```

Where i go from here is where i get hazey. Because i want to put the nested_span inside the nested_clone and then the nested_clone inside clone. I then want to run a loop where i clone the clone and append it to a container:

```
for(i=0; i < some_length; i++ ){ clone.appendTo("Container") }
```

The result is only a single Clone element in my DOM. any other solutions i have tested have failed so i hope someoen here can show me some javascript magic that i have yet to learn. Thank you!

Comment: You need a template solution, otherwise this will become unmanageable very quickly.  Check out Handlebars (http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Comment: `clone.clone().appendTo("Container")` ??? In your example, you were just moving same element at the end of container, again and again. That's said, you'd have better to use a template system as suggested above

Comment: If you need a templating system to create three elements and clone them in a loop, you should probably learn more jQuery !

Comment: @adeneo I guess OP wants more complex solution, i could be wrong

Comment: @A.Wolff - Probably, but a templating engine is still optional in my opinion. In some cases it makes things a lot easier, in other cases it's just overhead, at least in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to nest element into each other, you can use jQuery append method. http://api.jquery.com/append/

```
clone = $("<div></div>",{ class:"clone"});
nested_clone = $("<div></div>",{class:"nested_clone"});
nested_span = $("<span></span>");

finalElement = clone.append(nested_clone.append(nested_span));
```

**Another note:**
I usually prefer not to create HTML elements in Javascript, as they get much harder to manage. I would recommend creating a prototype element in the HTML document and reusing that.

```
<div class="clone prototype"><div class="nested_clone"><span><span></div></div>
```

Then in jQuery

```
$('.test').append($('.prototype').clone().removeClass('prototype'));
```

In CSS

```
.prototype {display: none;}
```

Comment: To your note: first `clone()` then `removeClass()` otherwise the prototype looses its class.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var container = $("#Container")
, clone = $("<div></div>",{ class:"clone"}) 
.append(
    $("<div></div>",{class:"nested_clone"})
    .append(
        $("<span></span>")
    )
)
, some_length = 5;
$.when(clone.appendTo(container), some_length)
.then(function(el, n) {
    do {
      el.clone().appendTo(container);
        --n
    } while (n > 0)
})
```

```js
var container = $("#Container")
, clone = $("<div>abc</div>",{ class:"clone"})
.append(
    $("<div>def</div>",{class:"nested_clone"})
    .append(
        $("<span>ghi</span>")
    )
)
, some_length = 5;
$.when(clone.appendTo(container), some_length)
.then(function(el, n) {
    do {
      el.clone().appendTo(container);
        --n
    } while (n > 0)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Container"></div>
```